# IMDB to SQLite: How to create table and insert imdb data into sqlite database?

Tags: database, sqlite, imdbpy

I'm working on a project where I want the select IMDB files (The files format is in *.list) that I downloaded from [here](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/ftp.imdb.com/pub/frozendata/) into a sqlite database. Unfortunately, I'm not able to solve this issue. I'm able to create a database but can't tabulate the table with IMDB data.

The documentation I've been following is [here.](https://imdbpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/ptdf.html) So far, I created a sqlite table but it will not populate it.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None

def create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    """    create a table from the create_table_sql statement
    :param conn: Connection object
    :param create_table_sql: a CREATE TABLE statement
    :return:

    """
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

def main():
    database = "/Users/Erudition/Desktop/imdb_database/sqldatabase.db"

    sql_create_tile_akas = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS title (
                                        titleid text PRIMARY KEY,
                                        ordering integer NOT NULL,
                                        title text,
                                        region text,
                                        language text NOT NULL,
                                        types text NOT NULL,
                                        attributes text NOT NULL,
                                        isOriginalTitle integer NOT NULL

                                    ); """

    conn = create_connection(database)
    if conn is not None:
        # create projects table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_tile_akas)

    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

In the terminal, I enter

```
 imdbpy2sql.py -d /Users/Erudition/Desktop/imdb_database/aka-titles.list/  
 -u sqlite:///sqldatabase.db'''
```

The output I expect is a sqlite table with all the rows filled. Instead, I get a several sqlite tables with nothing filled out.

The terminal output is:

```
WARNING The file will be skipped, and the contained
WARNING information will NOT be stored in the database.
WARNING Complete error:  [Errno 20] Not a directory: 
'/Users/Erudition/Desktop/imdb_database/aka-titles.list/complete- 
cast.list.gz'
WARNING WARNING WARNING
WARNING unable to read the "/Users/Erudition/Desktop/imdb_database/aka- 
titles.list/complete-crew.list.gz" file.
WARNING The file will be skipped, and the contained
WARNING information will NOT be stored in the database.
WARNING Complete error:  [Errno 20] Not a directory: 
'/Users/Erudition/Desktop/imdb_database/aka-titles.list/complete- 
crew.list.gz'
```

Comment: It looks like that script you found requires a *directory* as an argument when you're giving it a regular file instead.

Comment: as said by @Shawn you must specify a directory, in the -d argument. Plus, the files inside the directory must be .gz (so, do not decompress the .list.gz files)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

```
pip install imdb-sqlite
```

Then

```
imdb-sqlite
```

Here's the [link](https://pypi.org/project/imdb-sqlite/)